# dnsjava and Android

Tags: android, dnsjava

I have an Android app to which I am trying to add DNS SRV record detection. I know it is possible, based on the existence of apps such as [DNS Lookup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kodholken.dnslookup&hl=en), which I have installed, and it works just fine.

I am using dnsjava and this code runs fine as a stand-alone Java application on my machine, but when I run it on my Android device, I just get the "Error!" message:

```
Lookup lookup = new Lookup(serviceName, Type.SRV, DClass.IN);
Resolver resolver = new SimpleResolver();
lookup.setResolver(resolver);
lookup.setCache(null);
Record[] records = lookup.run();
if (lookup.getResult() == Lookup.SUCCESSFUL) {
    String responseMessage = null;
    String listingType = null;
    for (int i=0; i < records.length; i++) {
        if (records[i] instanceof SRVRecord) {
            listingType = ((SRVRecord) records[i]).toString()
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Found!");
    System.out.println("Response Message: "+responseMessage);
    System.out.println("Listing type: "+listingType);
} else if (lookup.getResult() == Lookup.HOST_NOT_FOUND) {
    System.out.println("Not found.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Error!");
}
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Using a very different setup for SRV lookup in Android; I found they always failed with a 'not found', unless I add the following to my Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment -- otherwise I would.

Make more else if statements, for example:

```
else if (lookup.getResult() == Lookup.HOST_NOT_FOUND) {
                    System.out.println("Not found.");
                } else if (lookup.getResult() == Lookup.TRY_AGAIN) {
                    System.out.println("Error!1");
                }  else if (lookup.getResult() == Lookup.TYPE_NOT_FOUND) {
                    System.out.println("Error!2");
                } else if (lookup.getResult() == Lookup.UNRECOVERABLE) {
                    System.out.println("Error!3");
                }
```

Also, try changing: `DClass.IN to DClass.ANY`